# Anime about boy & summoning monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I probably watched the anime anywhere from 6 to 10 years ago, it's hard to recall, from what I remember it was about a boy, probably anywhere from 14 years of age to older, had shorter to medium spikey hair, not as outlandishly spikey as vegetas, but more semi realistic, I'm not to sure on the hair color, I cant recall. I remember he was very serious all the time, the show in general was very serious, no comedy like other card game shows such as yu-gi-oh, I'm pretty sure it was the intention of the creators to make a serious anime to this genre as the market was flooded with light hearted silly card based animes at the time. I remember the boys eyes were serious looking, and smaller more realistic anime eyes, like those of the characters in *Attack on Titan*, and not the stereotypical cartoony anime eyes like those seen in *Yu-Gi-Oh*.

The boy gets transported to another world. In this new world he's transported to he is controlling real life monsters in battles, most are creature based like dragons and such, but I recall maybe he had a humanoid monster he would summon, that's what made him special, he was the only one or one of few that had humanoid summons. I'm not entirely sure if there was a card game involved at all but I thought that's how I originally found the anime is by looking for a card game type anime on the internet to watch. I remember starting to watch it thinking it was going to be another silly light-hearted card game type anime for kids, but being surprised that there was a much deeper and satisfying story and set of characters, I couldn't stop watching the show until I had finished it completely, he may have not used cards at all, I just remember he would always use his hands to summon monsters, like they were important or the monsters came out of his hands or something, I cant remember if it was because he was summoning them somehow with cards or other device or maybe just with his hands themselves.

Regardless the boy is now in this new world battling with these monsters, he may still be using cards in this new world to summon these monsters, I can't remember, and he gets mixed up in a war or conflict in this new world, there is a girl, I can't recall if she is a princess but I believe they end up falling in love, or at least he develops strong feelings for her. I remember the ending of the series pretty well, the boy ends up defeating the opposing army or series villain who the people he is helping are fighting against, and after maybe a heartfelt goodbye to the girl he developed feelings for, he is transported back to his own world. He is last seen in his own world on top of a building, possibly a skyscraper, or maybe even just a grassy hill, but pretty sure it was a metal building, I can't remember if he was in a wheel chair or not, with the wind blowing and possibly one of those huge metal wind turbines spinning in the background somewhere, and him swearing he'd make it back to that other world somehow to that girl, or at the very least he was thinking of her as they showed us she was also thinking of him.

The series wasn't too long if I recall, it may not have been more than 24 or so episodes, I really don't remember, it may have been closer to 54. I remember I watched it online and it was subtitled, to my knowledge I'm not sure if it has ever had an English release or dub.

Comment: Do you remember what the main character looked like? A physical description might help narrow down the search.

Comment: It's hard to remember, but I want to say he was short in stature, may e black hair and had serious looking eyes, he wasnt a very light hearted character, which is what leads me to believe he may have been in his mid to late teens, there really wasnt a lot of comedy in the series if anything despite it seeming like it was for kids, maybe it wasnt.

Comment: He was white, and I want to say he had short black hair that was a little spiky standing up, but not ridiculously like vegeta in DBZ, more realistic than that.

Comment: Here is a list of category/genre: Do you have a set of at least 3 that you are sure can be use to describe the anime?

Comment: Is there any chance this is simply "Yu-Gi-Oh!", during "The Noah's Arc" storyline (also known as the Virtual RPG arc), or "Yu-Gi-Oh! Capsule Monsters" (a miniseries where they are transported into the Capsule Monsters world)? They were pretty disjoint from the main series, so could easily be remembered as a separate franchise entirely.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Hey xdttransform, I dont see a list of categories

Comment: Was there supposed to be more text or a link attached to your comment?, also bilkokuya, it was definitely not yu-gi-oh, or any of its offshoots, I've looked at all of that franchises series and none of them match up or seem familiar with what I remember.

Comment: @Majortizzle, sorry failed the copy past [Here](https://myanimelist.net/info.php?go=genre)

Comment: What do the monsters look like, specifically? Were there any that looked human?

Comment: @laurel if I recall I remember a dragon type monster and other creatures similar to that, most of them were monster types like that, but I think there might have actually been a humanoid looking one that was specific to the main character, having that humanoid looking monster attached to him is what made him special, because it was probably one of the o ny if not the only humanoid looking monsters. I also remember wind played a big deal I think with the story or the main character, maybe that's why I remember the wind blowing and the wind turbine so prominently in the final episode.

Comment: Also @xdtTransform, after looking at the genre list link you included, the genre terms that best describe this anime are the following: Action, adventure, drama, fantasy.

Comment: Using those in [MyAnimeList Advanced Search](https://myanimelist.net/anime.php?q=&type=0&score=0&status=0&p=0&r=0&sm=0&sd=0&sy=0&em=0&ed=0&ey=0&c[0]=a&c[1]=b&c[2]=c&c[3]=f&gx=0&genre[0]=1&genre[1]=2&genre[2]=8&genre[3]=10&show=0). 
The only almost match is [Seisenshi Dunbine](https://myanimelist.net/anime/929/Seisenshi_Dunbine) we have the from tokyo to the other world, the war the love drama but no card only mecha humanoid and insectoid.

Comment: If the card are important well swaping gender of the hero gives Tenkuu No Escaflowne. But still have the world traveling romance with them beeing split and telling they will meet again. For car we have some tarot card, to see people future but no fight with them.

Comment: @Majortizzle looks like you have posted some comments on an existing answer refuting it. If possible, please include that info as an [edit] to the question to make it complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't remember a princess, but everything else sounds like Bakegyamon. It was a little earlier than 10 years ago, but only by a couple of years and you could have watched it a bit later.

[image]

> Without warning, Sanshiro is taken to a backwards universe to play
>   BakéGyamon--a game pitting monsters against monsters. Along the way he
>   meets other players who have a particular reason for being there--to
>   obtain the wish that is granted to the winner.

There are definitely cards and real monsters and the character development was quite good from memory.

Comment: Hey k mo, I watched a little bit of bakegyamon to see if it seemed familiar But unfortunately that isnt the anime I was looking for. The anime I'm talking about had a more serious tone to it, no comedy at all or jokiness from what I remember, the character design being a tad more realistic, less cartoony and childish looking. I just remember the main character being so very serious and acting like an adult, after looking at the main character of this bakegyamon anime, I'm also reconsiering that the main character had black hair, it was short & spikey, but now I'm not so sure it was black.

Comment: I feel like it was the creators intent to differentiate itself from all the other card based animes of the time, and tried to make an adult serial that wasnt really for kids or people who enjoyed shows like yu-gi-oh.

Comment: The main characters eyes weren't so large and animeish, they were smaller and more serious looking is the only way I can describe it, but still anime eyes, just not the huge large ones like in the example above, almost more like attack on titan eyes if that makes sense, more realistic in a sense.

Comment: @AaronChristian You can get rep by posting your own answers and questions and even through suggested edits, however, when editing please do not use it to post your own answer as the edit will generally just be rejected as it was here. You can normally answer questions but in this case the question is protected so you need a bit of rep before you can answer this question specifically.